# Get windows scale and layout in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to know if it is possible to get windows Scale and Layout (in percent) in Unity.
It is possible to do it in native C# application through:

```
public static int GetWindowsScaling()  
        {  
            return (int)(100 * Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth);  
        }
```

Would it be possible to do the same in Unity?

[image: Scale]

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps [Screen.DPI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-dpi.html). This should give you the scale factor against the reference DPI(usually 96).

Also, you can use `Screen.width` and `Screen.height` to get window width and height in pixels.

hope these help.

Comment: why does it remove 4 from 100%, 5 from 125% and 6 from 150%? Basically it outputs 96, 120, 144.